# Bestimmter Artikel mit Possessivpronomen

Tags: article, possessive-pronoun

> der/die/das ihre, der/die/das Ihre, die Ihren
>
> die deinen
>
> der/die/das seine

Can you please explain to me how these work? How can I use them? Can you please write for me some examples?

Comment: You probably mean *Possesiv*pronomen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

„Das Deine“ or „Das Ihre“ is quite old fashioned and it stands for something belonging to „you“ or „her“...

It would be used in sentences like

> Mein Wasser ist verbraucht, gib mir **das Deine**.

Translated as:

> My water is used up, give me **yours**.

Or -more romantic-:

> Sein Herz war gebrochen, darum gab sie ihm **das Ihre**.

Translated as:

> His heart was broken, so she gave him **hers**.

As written: today only poets would use this...

Comment: Sind dir die Satzendzeichen ausgegangen? ;)

Comment: habe noch ein paar gefunden und hinzugefügt, musste erst neue besorgen... ;)

Comment: Gar nicht so leicht in diesen Tagen! War der Satzendzeichenladen wohl doch offen?

Comment: Wir haben eine Inzidenz von unter 50... war also kein Problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, these expressions are used to start a subordinate clause, in which the object of the main clause (refered to by der/die/das) is described in more detail. Deinen/ihre/seine then refer to the object of the subordinate clause.

Examples:

„Ich gebe dir eine Antwort, die deinen Horizont erweitert.“
I give you an answer that broadens your horizon.

„Sie las das Buch, das ihre Lieblingsgeschichte enthält.“
She read the book that contained her favorite story.

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat flawed, since the personal pronouns mentioned are actually used as substantives in the examples I imagined (no ones were given) and have to start with an uppercase letter. A simple example is the counterpiece of the Latin *Suum cuique*:

> Jedem das Seine. (English: To each his own.)

The only other use I encounter more frequently is

> Grüße mir die Deinen! (Greetings to your family!)

where *Deinen* summarizes husband, children and may also cover pets or parents if living in the same house and is much more elegant than enumerating all of them.

Comment: Not to forget that they are substantives derived from *possesive* pronouns.